# How to move a spider?

Tags: insects

There is a small spider in one of the rooms in my apartment (I should probably post a picture of it).

There is another room with a lot of potted plans which attract small flies. I would like to move the spider there in order to both give it a feast and get rid of some of the flies.

My concerns:

- this is going to destroy its whole web
- the new room is quite sunny.

The flies gather at the most sunny window and die there (*small* flies). How to relocate the guy with maximum chance for it to survive?

---

Epilogue:

The spider is alive and well, making webs and catching flies. I tried moving a spider of another variety (long-legged house spider) and although they look slower, they are blazingly fast as well. The enclosed **large** container proposed by @alephzero is an excellent idea. Else they just run off if carried on a piece of A4 paper.

Comment: Just catch it (in a container) and move it. Most spiders can live for months without food so it won't die of hunger without a web, and many web-building spiders make a new web every day anyway - though they may "recycle" the old web by eating it, if it hasn't been destroyed by bad weather or for some other reason.

Comment: @alephzero I am scared of killing it with: 1. too much light and heat 2. new room 3: moving it when it's too starving and weak to make a new web 4. exposing it to too much/little light/moisture/oxygen/wind/plant matter.

Comment: @alephzero I didn't really follow your advice and am now very sorry. I made an OPEN paper container, struggled to lure that nimble guy onto it, then carried it to the second room but failed to plant him onto the dark but fly-infested corner above the window. Will report back if I see spiderwebs and a tiny agile friend among them.

Comment: YES! It is alive! I will not mess with it's life anymore - it knows quite better than me what is best for it. Will still report if (hopefully when) I see it's webs.

Comment: At least some spiders (e.g. bold jumping spiders) appreciate a water source, and can suffer without one (which is why I believe that they often come to sinks). I once found one dying of thirst on the floor, and when I gave it a drop of water, it quickly started drinking it. I'm not sure the best way to manually supply a spider with water, but you might consider thinking about it.